# using BERT for article summarization where label or expected output summary is not present for the article

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a project where I have constraints that I can not use the Extractive methods to summarize an article and have to use BERT for this. If if this would have been a labelling problem (summarizing tweets, comments, questions) where I have the respective labels for the train data, I would have used the vectors from BERT as an input to `Keras` embedding layer with `LSTM` and build a model that with input and output labels. But the problem is that I have to summarize the text rather thhose labelled tweets and comments. Is there any I way (I am sure there is because I have been asked so specifically) that I can use BERT when I have the vectors corresponding the vocabulary?

Comment: could you add an example data sample and the expected output - this would facilitate understanding your question.

Comment: that is the problem. I do not have any expected output. Input is any document say my question above. You and I can summarise that I want to use BERT for documents which do not have any expected output

Comment: If you expect nothing, everything will do ;)

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot. That was helpful will build a state of the art model based on this right away!

Comment: Sorry about that. But still it would help me to see a sample input and the corresponding output you wish to receive from the model!

Comment: @chefhose I am given some documents (banks, investment etc) and I am asked to summarise the documents using ```BERT```. No other information is given. These documents are simply your everyday legal documents. Do I get some data online and train on that data to build my model but where could I find legal documents that that too like Indian Banks format?

Comment: I could have used ```seq2seq ->  LSTM+ Attention ``` but then again, it need the labels. How would  ```BERT/GloVe``` embeddings with cosine similarity act in your opinion as any NN would require labels for sure during training.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of documents which you like to summarize automatically, but you do not have any training data. I assume your documents are in english. Luckily BERT is a pretrained model, there are even libaries which are specialized for summarization and very easy to use. Have you tried if one of those meet your goals?
For example [bert-extractive-summarizer](https://pypi.org/project/bert-extractive-summarizer/) :

```
from summarizer import Summarizer

body = ''' Indian Bank is an Indian state-owned financial services company established in 1907 and headquartered in Chennai, India. 
It has 20,924 employees, 2900 branches with 2861 ATMs and 1014 cash deposit machines and is one of the top performing public sector banks in India. 
Total business of the bank has touched ₹430,000 crore (US$60 billion) as on 31 March 2019. Bank's Information Systems & Security processes certified with ISO27001:2013 standard and is among very few Banks certified worldwide. 
It has overseas branches in Colombo and Singapore including a Foreign Currency Banking Unit at Colombo and Jaffna. It has 227 Overseas Correspondent banks in 75 countries.
Since 1969, the Government of India has owned the bank. As per the announcement made by the Indian Finance Minister Nirmala Sitharaman on 30 August 2019, Indian Bank will be anchor bank for the Kolkata-based Allahabad Bank, and this merger is expected to come on force from 1 April 2020, making it the seventh largest bank in the country. '''


model = Summarizer()
result = model(body, min_length=60)
full = ''.join(result)
print(full)
```

Output:

> Indian Bank is an Indian state-owned financial services company established in 1907 and headquartered in Chennai, India. Total business of the bank has touched ₹430,000 crore (US$60 billion) as on 31 March 2019.